# Reflection invoke throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

what am i missing here?

I get the exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    Class<?> clazz=entity.getClass();   
    System.out.println("   Clazzz is:"+clazz);
    Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

      for(Method method : methods){
          if(method.getName().startsWith("get") && String.class.equals(method.getReturnType())){
              System.out.println("getter: " + method);

                 try {
                    String s=(String) method.invoke(clazz,(Object[]) null); //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
                    System.out.println(" value in s is:"+s);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write

```
String s=(String) method.invoke(entity, (Object[]) null);
```

The first parameter of `Method.invoke` is null for static methods or the object on which the method should be invoked.